# Simulator architecture appears to be unsupported in ios simulator even after using the simulator build(.app) in appium

Tags: appium-ios

Simulator architecture appears to be unsupported by the '/Users/anakin/Downloads/MKETradeSIT 7.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.

Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1537497609020 (10:40:09 GMT+0800 (+08))
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":"Failed to launch com.mayBank.MKETradeSIT application","sessionId":"956BB2D5-5E60-404B-BF82-592F1C655C5D","status":13}
[XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying...
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1537497658840 (10:40:58 GMT+0800 (+08))
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com.mayBank.MKETradeSIT","arguments":[],"environment":

Answer (score 1):

@Manish - You just confirm the given .app is supported on real iPhone device, if yes then it won't work on simulator, for simulator you need to get different build.

Generally in Xcode we can generate two different builds one for real device which is not run on iPhone simulator other one is simulator supported build which is not run on real devices

Comment: Yeah, But how exactly we generate build for simulators? Is it specific to one simulator or it would work in any simulator?

Comment: Basically, if you generate an iPhone simulator build, it should work for all simulators. no need to generate simulator specific build.